# Existence of continuous surjection from open unit square to closed unit square

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Does there exists a continuous surjection from (0,1)×(0,1) to [0,1]×[0,1]? 
I have found such a function from (0,1) to [0,1]. I just want to generalize it.

Comment: Give the surjection in the 1D case so we can see how to do the 2D one.

Comment: @Parcly got the way to generalise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f: (0,1) \to [0,1]$ is a continuous surjection, then $F(x,y)=(f(x), f(y))$ is also continuous and onto from $(0,1)^2$ to $[0,1]^2$.